# Give an example of a pair of real-valued function f and g defined on R for which f is not differentiable at 0, g is not differentiable at f(0)...

Tags: real-analysis

Give an example of a pair of real-valued function f and g defined on $\mathbb{R}$ for which f is not differentiable at 0, g is not differentiable at f(0) but for which $g \circ f$ is differentiable at 0.

I honestly can't even wrap my mind around this. So some hints would be helpful! Thank you!

Comment: yes! my bad! @Arthur I'm editing it now

Comment: @chappers i think it. I searched for this so hard and could not find it so thank you for sharing that!

Answer (score 3):

What about taking

$$f=g\,\quad\text{defined by }\quad f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\1-x&x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}?$$

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use $f(x)=|x|$, and let $g$ be along the lines of
$$
g(x)=\cases{0&$x\geq0$\\ \text{something really ugly} & $x<0$}
$$